# Can I exclude a dependency from being included in JUnit tests run from IntelliJ?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit

I'm using JUnit 4/Mockito/PowerMock for a unit test suite for a legacy application.  PowerMock has a dependency on javassist: `org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:test`

We also have a dependency on an old version of Hibernate which pulls in an older version of javassist: `javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.0.GA:compile`

The older version of javassist messes with the unit tests, causing a cryptic exception: `java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18`

When running the tests directly through Maven, I'm able to fix the problem by excluding the older jar from the unit test run in the POM.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <classpathDependencyExcludes>
            <!-- our version of Hibernate pulls in a javassist dependency that is incompatible with Java8
                this can be removed once we upgrade Hibernate -->
            <classpathDependencyExclude>javassist:javassist</classpathDependencyExclude>
        </classpathDependencyExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When running the tests directly in IntelliJ, however, the error still occurs.  It's a major problem not being able to debug the tests easily from the IDE, so I'd love if there were some way to get IntelliJ to exclude that old dependency as well, until we can finally upgrade our Hibernate dependency.

Comment: Exclude the dependency from the dependency directly instead only in maven-surefire-plugin configuration...

Comment: Unfortunately the actual production code doesn't work when using the newer version of Javassist. Until we can upgrade our Hibernate version, we're stuck with needing the old Javassist dependency at compile time.

Comment: For anyone finding this later on, there is a active issue on jetbrains with this problem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122783